# C: why no & for strings in scanf() function?

Tags: c, string, scanf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't scanf need an ampersand for strings and also works fine in printf (in C)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931850/why-doesnt-scanf-need-an-ampersand-for-strings-and-also-works-fine-in-printf-i)

In C when we use the `scanf()` function to get user input, we always use the `&` sign before the variable.
For example:

```
  scanf("%d", &number);
  scanf("%c", &letter);
```

This ensures our input is stored in proper address. But in case of a string we do not use `&`.

Why is that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A "string" in C is the address of a character buffer.
You want `scanf` to fill the memory in the buffer, which is pointed to by the variable.

In contrast, an `int` is a block of memory, not an address.  In order for `scanf` to fill that memory, you need to pass its address.

Answer (score 1):

Since the identifier `buf` in `char buf[512];` degrades to a pointer to the first element of the array you don't need to specify a pointer to the buffer in the argument to `scanf`. By passing `&buf` the pointer passed to scanf is now a doubly-indirect pointer (it is a pointer to a pointer to the beginning of the buffer) and will likely cause the program to crash or other bad behaviour.