# Why does it keep on giving me this error in c

Tags: c, macos

```
float fahrenheit;
float celsius;
float formulaf = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5/9;
char str[20];
float formulac = celsius * 9/5 + 32.0;
printf("Choose either fahrenheit or celsius; ");
scanf("%*s", &str);
if (strcmp(str, "fahrenheit") ==0)
{
    printf("Enter the temperature in fahrenheit: ");
    scanf("%f", &fahrenheit);
    printf("%.2f fahrenheit is %.2f celsius", fahrenheit, formulaf);
}
else
{
    printf("Enter the temperature in celsius: ");
    scanf("%f", &celsius);
    printf("%.2f celsius is %.2f fahrenheit", celsius, formulac);
}
```

I'm coding this in xcode, I have created the headers and everything, this is the main part where I am stuck, it gives an error in the following code and it gives breakpoints in some other lines, please help me solve this

`scanf("%*s", &s);` -------> data argument not used by format string

what does this mean?

Comment: You need to study how integers and floating point variables work. `5/9` doesn't make any sense in C, for example.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, hhehehe

Answer (score 2):

If you read e.g. [this `scanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you will see that the `"*"` modifier in the format string means the scanned string will not be used.

Also, when scanning for strings, you should not use the address-of operator, as strings already are pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`%*s` instructs `scanf` to scan and discard the sting scanned. The compiler is complaining because the second argument of that `scanf`(`&s`) is not used.

You probably wanted to use `%s` or `%19s`(tells `scanf` to scan a maximum of 19 characters + 1 for the NUL-terminator) which prevent buffer overflows.

Also change the second argument of `scanf` to `s`. This is done because `%s` expects a `char*` while `&s` is of type `char(*)[20]`. `s` gets converted into `&s[0]`, a `char*`, exactly what `%s` expects.

So the `scanf`

```
scanf("%*s", &str);
```

should be

```
scanf("%s", str);
```

for the reasons explained above.

---

BTW, Your code exhibits Undefined Behavior because when you use

```
float formulaf = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5/9;
```

and

```
float formulac = celsius * 9/5 + 32.0;
```

`farenheit` and `celsius` are uninitialized. Move it after they get initialized,i.e, move it after

```
scanf("%f", &fahrenheit);
```

and

```
scanf("%f", &celsius);
```

respectively.

Comment: And can you please explain why should i not use &str in my code ?

Comment: @user5032369 , It might have worked for your friend. But undefined behavior is undefined. It might work, might not, or do something weird. It might stop working on adding a simple `printf` somewhere etc etc. Read the third paragraph of my answer to know why you need to use `str` instead of `&str`. Alternatively, browse through similar questions on StackOverflow like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921617/c-why-no-for-strings-in-scanf-function)