# &string_name or string_name for %s to print string in C

Tags: c, string, printf

If I have below string in C:

```
char s[]="Question";
```

Then I noted that both of the below prtintf prints the string correctly in terminal.

1.

```
printf("%s\n",s);
```

2.

```
printf("%s\n",&s);
```

Which is a correct way to print the string in C. If both of them are same, then what is the convention followed ? 1 or 2 ?

Thanks.

Comment: The second one is undefined behavior. The first one is correct. [C-faq 12.12b](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1a.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't scanf need an ampersand for strings and also works fine in printf (in C)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931850/why-doesnt-scanf-need-an-ampersand-for-strings-and-also-works-fine-in-printf-i)

Comment: the name of an array, in C, degrades to the address of the array.  so printf( "%s", array ) is correct.  using printf("%s", &array); is saying print the address of the address of the array, which is not defined and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char s[]="Question";
printf("%s\n",&s);
```

is undefined behavior because,

> §7.21.6.1/8 The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> [...]
>
> s          If no l
>   length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the
>   initial element of             an array of character type.
>
> §7.21.6.1/9 [...] If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

`s` in this context will decay to a pointer type. Since `&` yields a pointer, the type you're passing to `printf` is actually a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is correct, for the second one you should get a warning from your compiler, since it's UB, something like:

```
[Warning] format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *'
```