# Arrays as arguments when used with **characters** VS with **integers**

Tags: c, arrays, string, character, scanf

I had encountered a contradiction - in my point of view - when using arrays as arguments in `scanf()` function with characters and with integers. in Deitel and Deitel book, I was studying character handling library and it introduced that when - for instance - assigning: `"char word[ 20 ]"` and then `"scanf( "%s", word );"`, here the `scanf()` function doesn't need the `&` operator. But when assigning: `"int array[ 10 ]"` and then when scanning the input from the user, here it needs the `&` operator!! 
Could anybody explain this for me please ?

Comment: Please give an example to your `scanf` with integer arrays. Usally it's `scanf("%d", &array[i])` or `scanf("%d", array+i)`....... in a char array the `%s` scans into a string, not a char, therefore it uses the entire array....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't scanf need an ampersand for strings and also works fine in printf (in C)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931850/why-doesnt-scanf-need-an-ampersand-for-strings-and-also-works-fine-in-printf-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to remember:

First of all, unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  So when you pass an *array* expression to a function like `scanf`, what the function actually receives is a pointer to the first element.

Secondly, the `%s` conversion specifier will read a *sequence* of characters until it sees a whitespace character or hits end-of-file, and it stores that sequence to the array starting at the passed address.  By contrast, the `%c` conversion specifier only reads a single character from the input stream and stores it to the passed address.

Answer (score 1):

```
char word[20];
scanf("%s", word);
```

It will read the whole string (collection of characters) the user typed into `word`. So if I type "Hi", then `word[0]` would be `'H'` and `word[1]` would be `'i'`.

```
int array[10];
scanf("%d", &array[0]); // Stores the number the user typed into 'array[0]'
scanf("%d", &array[1]); // Stores the number the user typed into 'array[1]'
```

Here we use the `&`, but also we access an element of the array, since the format specifier `%d` is for a number.

In order to get the analogy, consider this example:

```
char word[20];
scanf("%c", &word[0]);
scanf("%c", &word[1]);
```

Here the format specifier, is asking for a character (and *not* a collection of characters (i.e. a string)).

Comment: So the idea here is in the conversion specifier, right ?

Comment: Exactly @MuhammadFouadAlharoon, welcome to Stack overflow!